# Problem with deleting input in an array method delete

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to delete an added input, I get an error message that Value is NULL.
So the idea is, when I click on DELETE, only inputs are deleted and not all inputs.
the function myFunction (), there input is added to the array.
actually I would also like to use Up Down but first Delete has to work, but if you have an idea how I can do Up and Dwon, please write the answer.

```js
var Array = [];

function myFunction() {
  //console.log('test');
  var todoItem = document.getElementById('new-todo-item').value;
  const Input = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="todo-item-done"]');
  console.log(Input.value);

  //Input von Add
  Array.unshift(todoItem);
  document.getElementById("todo-list").innerHTML +=
    "<li>" + 
      "<input type='text'" + " name='todo-item-done'" +
        " class='todo-item-done'" + " value='" + todoItem +
      "'> " +
      "<a id= 'myDIV' class='up' onclick='UpDown()' href='#'>" + "up"+"</a>" +
      " | " +
      "<a class='down' onclick='UpDown()' href='#'>" + "down"+"</a> " +
      "<button onclick='deleteData()' class='todo-item-delete'>Delete</button>" +
    "</li>"
  ;
  
  document.getElementById('new-todo-item').value = "";
}

function deleteData() {
var deleteValue = document.getElementsByName('todo-item-done').value;
  var index = Array.indexOf(deleteValue);
  if (index !== -1) {
    Array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<label for="todo">To do:</label>
<input type="text" id="new-todo-item">
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" id="add-todo-item" value="add the todo">
<ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Change `if (index !== -1) {` to `if (index > -1) {` or `if (index != -1) {`

Comment: the Problem is here:  var deleteValue = document.getElementById('todo-item-done').value;   (error= Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null)

Comment: Indeed, the code does say `input[name="todo-item-done"]` which implies that the item has it as a `name` not the `id`

Comment: what should I do now to get the correct one?

Comment: **Do not** name a variable `Array`. that will overwrite the inbuilt `Array` object.

Comment: If you have not used `id` but have used `name` instead, you can use `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementById`.  However, this does return a collection - so you will have to have `document.getElementsByName('new-todo-item')[0].value` to get the value out of the first one.  Ideally, you should change the element to use an `id` as that is the recommended way.  As of HTML5, the `name` attribute has been deprecated [getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Comment: I did it and the error message is gone but nothing is deleted.
Code now looks like this. function deleteData()
  {
 //   const Input = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="todo-item-done"]');
//console.log(Input.value);
var deleteValue = document.getElementsByName('todo-item-done').value;
    var index = Array.indexOf(deleteValue);
 if (index !== -1) {
    Array.splice(index, 1);
}
  }

Comment: `onclick='deleteData("todoItem")'` + `function deleteData(deleteValue)`.

Comment: @iAmOren this is impossible because I have to delete the selected input.
Add 3 inputs and then run the code so you can understand what I meant

Comment: @ATD Add 3 inputs and then run the code so you can understand what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:  Firstly, as Matt pointed out, you should not use `Array` as a variable name - it is a reserved word - so change `Array` to `arr`.  Secondly, the Delete button needs to target the `input` tag in the same `li` element.  So, changing the variable name and targeting the right `input` tag, I get:

```js
var arr = [];

function myFunction() {
  //console.log('test');
  var todoItem = document.getElementById('new-todo-item').value;
  const Input = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="todo-item-done"]');
  //console.log(Input.value);

  //Input von Add
  arr.unshift(todoItem);
  document.getElementById("todo-list").innerHTML +=
    "<li>" + 
      "<input type='text'" + " name='todo-item-done'" +
        " class='todo-item-done'" + " value='" + todoItem +
      "'> " +
      "<a id= 'myDIV' class='up' onclick='UpDown()' href='#'>" + "up"+"</a>" +
      " | " +
      "<a class='down' onclick='UpDown()' href='#'>" + "down"+"</a> " +
      "<button onclick='deleteData(this)' class='todo-item-delete'>Delete</button>" +
    "</li>"
  ;
  
  document.getElementById('new-todo-item').value = "";
}

function deleteData(e) {
  console.log(arr);
  let p = e.parentNode;
  console.log(p);
  let deleteValue = p.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var index = arr.indexOf(deleteValue);
  if (index !== -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  p.remove();
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<label for="todo">To do:</label>
<input type="text" id="new-todo-item">
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" id="add-todo-item" value="add the todo">
<ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Note that I have changed the Delete button's onclick to include `this` so that the code knows which button has been clicked.

Comment: first thanks for the answer, I saw on the console that the selected element was deleted from the array, but it always shows up on Borwser? I want that to be deleted from the browser too

Comment: Ok - I've updated the code to do that.  As the code was looking at the parent of the delete button, it is just a case of doing `p.remove()` to delete it